why does coming this error when in visual studio terminal?
pipenv : The term 'pipenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pipenv django
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipenv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

i want to install pipenv Django

Have you installed pipenv? What does the command pip list output?
